# Reading Message from MSMQ using C++

Tags: c++, msmq

I am currently working on a C++ application that will read the message from the MSMQ.....
this is the code that I ran :

```
HRESULT ReadingDestQueue(
WCHAR * wszQueueName,
WCHAR * wszComputerName
)
{

// Define the required constants and variables.  
const int NUMBEROFPROPERTIES = 5;
DWORD cPropId = 0;
HRESULT hr = MQ_OK;                                 // Return code  
HANDLE hQueue = NULL;                               // Queue handle  
ULONG ulBufferSize = 2;

// Define an MQMSGPROPS structure.  
MQMSGPROPS msgprops;
MSGPROPID aMsgPropId[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
MQPROPVARIANT aMsgPropVar[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
HRESULT aMsgStatus[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];

// Specify the message properties to be retrieved.  
aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_LABEL_LEN;           // Property ID  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_UI4;                   // Type indicator  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].ulVal = MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN;  // Length of label  
cPropId++;

WCHAR wszLabelBuffer[MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN];         // Label buffer  
aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_LABEL;               // Property ID  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_LPWSTR;                // Type indicator  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].pwszVal = wszLabelBuffer;      // Label buffer  
cPropId++;

UCHAR * pucBodyBuffer = NULL;
pucBodyBuffer = (UCHAR*)malloc(ulBufferSize);
if (pucBodyBuffer == NULL)
{
    return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}
memset(pucBodyBuffer, 0, ulBufferSize);
aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY_SIZE;           // Property ID  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_NULL;                  // Type indicator  
cPropId++;

aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY;                // Property ID  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1;       // Type indicator  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.pElems = (UCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer;  // Body buffer  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.cElems = ulBufferSize;    // Buffer size  
cPropId++;

aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY_TYPE;           // Property ID  
aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_NULL;                  // Type indicator  
cPropId++;

// Initialize the MQMSGPROPS structure.  
msgprops.cProp = cPropId;                           // Number of message properties  
msgprops.aPropID = aMsgPropId;                      // IDs of the message properties  
msgprops.aPropVar = aMsgPropVar;                    // Values of the message properties  
msgprops.aStatus = aMsgStatus;                      // Error reports  

                                                    // Validate the input strings.  
if (wszQueueName == NULL || wszComputerName == NULL)
{
    return MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
}

// Create a direct format name.  
WCHAR * wszFormatName = NULL;
DWORD dwFormatNameLength = 0;
dwFormatNameLength = wcslen(wszQueueName) + wcslen(wszComputerName) + 12;
wszFormatName = new WCHAR[dwFormatNameLength];
if (wszFormatName == NULL)
{
    return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}
memset(wszFormatName, 0, dwFormatNameLength);
// ************************************  
// You must concatenate "DIRECT=OS:", wszComputerName, "\",   
// and wszQueueName into the wszFormatName buffer.  
// wszFormatName = "DIRECT=OS:" + wszComputerName + "\" +     
// wszQueueName  
// If the format name is too long for the buffer, return FALSE.  
// ************************************  

// Open the queue with receive access.  
hr = MQOpenQueue(
    wszFormatName,                      // Format name of the queue  
    MQ_RECEIVE_ACCESS,                  // Access mode  
    MQ_DENY_NONE,                       // Share mode  
    &hQueue                             // OUT: Queue handle  
);
// Free the memory that was allocated for the format name string.  
if (wszFormatName)
{
    delete[] wszFormatName;
}

// Handle any error returned by MQOpenQueue.  
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}

for (; ; )
{
    aMsgPropVar[0].ulVal = MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN;
    hr = MQReceiveMessage(
        hQueue,                     // Queue handle  
        1000,                       // Max time to (msec) to receive the message  
        MQ_ACTION_RECEIVE,          // Receive action  
        &msgprops,                  // Message property structure  
        NULL,                       // No OVERLAPPED structure  
        NULL,                       // No callback function  
        NULL,                       // No cursor handle  
        MQ_NO_TRANSACTION           // Not in a transaction  
    );

    if (hr == MQ_ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        ulBufferSize = aMsgPropVar[2].ulVal * sizeof(UCHAR);
        pucBodyBuffer = (UCHAR*)realloc(pucBodyBuffer, ulBufferSize);
        if (pucBodyBuffer == NULL)
        {
            return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        }
        memset(pucBodyBuffer, 0, ulBufferSize);
        aMsgPropVar[3].caub.pElems = (UCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer;
        aMsgPropVar[3].caub.cElems = ulBufferSize;
        continue;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"No messages. Closing queue\n");
        break;
    }

    // If the message contains a label, print it.  
    if (msgprops.aPropVar[0].ulVal == 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"Removed message from queue.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Removed message '%s' from queue.\n", wszLabelBuffer);
    }

    // If the message body is a string, display it.  
    if (msgprops.aPropVar[4].ulVal == VT_BSTR)
    {
        wprintf(L"Body: %s", (WCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer);
        wprintf(L"\n");
    }
}

// Close the queue and free the memory allocated for the body buffer.  
hr = MQCloseQueue(hQueue);
free(pucBodyBuffer);

return hr;
}

int main()
{
WCHAR wszComputerName =(WCHAR)L"wsm-ela-inc5";
WCHAR wszQueueName = (WCHAR)L"private$\\soorya1";
_com_error err(ReadingDestQueue(&wszQueueName, &wszComputerName));
LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
wcout << errMsg;
return 0;
}
```

this is my MSMQ queue : 
[image: Queue property]

when I run this...I am getting an error code of "0xC00E001E" (MQ_ERROR_ILLEGAL_FORMATNAME (0xC00E001E)

Returned when the specified format name is not valid)

any methods to recover this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the format name itself did the trick!
here is the code :

```
// ReadMsg.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "mq.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include"comdef.h"
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;

HRESULT ReadingDestQueue( LPWSTR lpwcsFormatName)
{

    // Define the required constants and variables.  
    const int NUMBEROFPROPERTIES = 5;
    DWORD cPropId = 0;
    HRESULT hr = MQ_OK;                                 // Return code  
    HANDLE hQueue = NULL;                               // Queue handle  
    ULONG ulBufferSize = 2;

    // Define an MQMSGPROPS structure.  
    MQMSGPROPS msgprops;
    MSGPROPID aMsgPropId[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
    MQPROPVARIANT aMsgPropVar[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];
    HRESULT aMsgStatus[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES];

    // Specify the message properties to be retrieved.  
    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_LABEL_LEN;           // Property ID  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_UI4;                   // Type indicator  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].ulVal = MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN;  // Length of label  
    cPropId++;

    WCHAR wszLabelBuffer[MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN];         // Label buffer  
    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_LABEL;               // Property ID  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_LPWSTR;                // Type indicator  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].pwszVal = wszLabelBuffer;      // Label buffer  
    cPropId++;

    UCHAR * pucBodyBuffer = NULL;
    pucBodyBuffer = (UCHAR*)malloc(ulBufferSize);
    if (pucBodyBuffer == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    memset(pucBodyBuffer, 0, ulBufferSize);
    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY_SIZE;           // Property ID  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_NULL;                  // Type indicator  
    cPropId++;

    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY;                // Property ID  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1;       // Type indicator  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.pElems = (UCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer;  // Body buffer  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.cElems = ulBufferSize;    // Buffer size  
    cPropId++;

    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY_TYPE;           // Property ID  
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_NULL;                  // Type indicator  
    cPropId++;

    // Initialize the MQMSGPROPS structure.  
    msgprops.cProp = cPropId;                           // Number of message properties  
    msgprops.aPropID = aMsgPropId;                      // IDs of the message properties  
    msgprops.aPropVar = aMsgPropVar;                    // Values of the message properties  
    msgprops.aStatus = aMsgStatus;                      // Error reports  

    // Validate the input strings.  
    if (lpwcsFormatName == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    // Open the queue with receive access.  
    hr = MQOpenQueue(
        lpwcsFormatName,                      // Format name of the queue  
        MQ_RECEIVE_ACCESS,                  // Access mode  
        MQ_DENY_NONE,                       // Share mode  
        &hQueue                             // OUT: Queue handle  
    );

    // Handle any error returned by MQOpenQueue.  
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {

        return hr;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        aMsgPropVar[0].ulVal = MQ_MAX_MSG_LABEL_LEN;
        hr = MQReceiveMessage(
            hQueue,                     // Queue handle  
            1000,                       // Max time to (msec) to receive the message  
            MQ_ACTION_RECEIVE,          // Receive action  
            &msgprops,                  // Message property structure  
            NULL,                       // No OVERLAPPED structure  
            NULL,                       // No callback function  
            NULL,                       // No cursor handle  
            MQ_NO_TRANSACTION           // Not in a transaction  
        );

        if (hr == MQ_ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
        {
            ulBufferSize = aMsgPropVar[2].ulVal * sizeof(UCHAR);
            pucBodyBuffer = (UCHAR*)realloc(pucBodyBuffer, ulBufferSize);
            if (pucBodyBuffer == NULL)
            {
                return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
            }
            memset(pucBodyBuffer, 0, ulBufferSize);
            aMsgPropVar[3].caub.pElems = (UCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer;
            aMsgPropVar[3].caub.cElems = ulBufferSize;
            continue;
        }

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wprintf(L"No messages. Closing queue\n");
            break;
        }

        // If the message contains a label, print it.  
        if (msgprops.aPropVar[0].ulVal == 0)
        {
            wprintf(L"Removed message from queue.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Removed message '%s' from queue.\n", (char *)wszLabelBuffer);
            //cout << "Removed message ";
            //wcout << wszLabelBuffer;
            //cout << "from queue.\n";
        }

        // If the message body is a string, display it.  
        if (msgprops.aPropVar[4].ulVal == VT_BSTR)
        {
            wprintf(L"Body: %s", (WCHAR*)pucBodyBuffer);
            wprintf(L"\n");
        }

    }

    // Close the queue and free the memory allocated for the body buffer.  
    hr = MQCloseQueue(hQueue);
    free(pucBodyBuffer);
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    LPWSTR  lpwcsFormatName = (LPWSTR)L"DIRECT=OS:wsm-ela-inc5\\private$\\soorya97";
    _com_error err(ReadingDestQueue(lpwcsFormatName));
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    wcout << errMsg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```